# Error when template parameter passed to boost multi index container

Tags: templates, parameters, containers, boost-multi-index

**I am trying to use multi_index_container with templates. below is my code.**

```
template < class ValueType >
class anrQueue
{
private:
    typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    ValueType,
    indexed_by<
    sequenced<>,
    ordered_unique<identity<ValueType> >
    >
    > a_queue;

a_queue mQueue;

public:
size_t remove(const ValueType& x) {
    return mQueue.get<1>().erase(x);
}
-------------------------^
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

How to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
return mQueue.template get<1>().erase(x);
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for an explanation on the usage of `template` on dependent contexts.